# Verify user's signature in contract

Tags: smart-contract, public-key

User A has signed a message `msg` with signature `sig`.How can the third party verify this message in a contract? The verify method contract is like this:

`void verify_user_sig(account_name user,string msg,string sig,public_key pubkey);`

Because we can know `user`,`msg`,`sig` and user's `pubkey` ,we can recover the public key in contract.But the problem is how can we know that the `pubkey` submitted is the user's public key ?

**So the question is:**
 How to get the account name of a public key in contract?

Comment: It does not make sense to do crypto validation in the smart contract, that is way too expensive.

Answer (score 1):

There is no system table that stores the relation between accounts and public keys. Therefore, it is not possible to get account names from a public key in a contract.

Cleos is using the history plugin of nodeos to get the account names from a public key. (https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/8f0f54cf0c15c4d08b60c7de4fd468c5a8b38f2f/programs/cleos/httpc.hpp#L108)

The table of the history plugin is updated e.g. through the `updateauth` action (
https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/2232802dee4be1a3f6ca436edad64af3c45d7029/plugins/history_plugin/history_plugin.cpp#L239)